# How to launch a "log(all parameters)" request at the beginning of all methods

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, nlog

I'm working on C# project, which all use `NLog` reference for logging purposes.

As a result, everywhere in the project I can add the line `log.Debug("...")` and some logging will be shown.

One of my colleagues has written a project, applying lots of classes and methods, but the logging is far too little. What I would like, is for every method to launch the following line at the beginning of its execution:

```
log.Debug(<list of input parameters>);  // all parameters have a ToString() method
```

In order to achieve that, I'm thinking of some kind of a base method, like this (pseudo-code):

```
private <whatever_output_type> base_method(...){
  startup : 
    string output = "";
    for each (param) in GetParameters():
      output += ", " + param.ToString();
    log.Debug(<this_method_name>, output);
}
```

Then I do the following for every existing method:
Replace:

```
private void Method1 (int i1, int i2, string S1, SomeClass obj1)
{ ... }
public void Method2 ()
{ ... }
```

By:

```
private void Method1 (int i1, int i2, string S1, SomeClass obj1) : base_method
{ ... }
public void Method2 () : base_method
{ ... }
```

In order to get a more readable logging, I would use indentation, based on callstack framecount, as explained in [this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.framecount?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_StackTrace_FrameCount), but let's first start making this work.

For that, I need the following:

- How can I retrieve the full list of input parameters of a random method?
- How can I mention that something must be done at the start of a method and how to I inherit one method from a basic function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't do this from C# code alone; methods can access declared parameter lists, but the contents of parameters at runtime is not available through stack traces or other introspection (at least, there is no managed interface for this). Look into AOP frameworks like PostSharp (disclaimer: no personal experience) to weave this into code before execution. Profilers are another alternative (typically they only do simple counts, but there is no reason they can't log parameter values), but you don't really want to be writing these manually either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe combine this:

```
public static void InfoParams(this ILoggger logger, params object[] list)
{
    logger.Info("{@params}", (object)list);
}
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

You could also consider using one of these:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tracer.4NLog.Fody/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Anotar.NLog.Fody/